Error while using scanf for user inout in C
I am trying to make a script which will need an integer as user input.
    printf("What is your guess?\n--> ");
    int guess;
    scanf("%d", &guess);

But when I try to run and compile it using gcc in VSCode, the code doesn't stop running and doesn't output anything. When I use Ctrl+C it says code=null.
When I do it via my terminal, it works just fine.
What am I doing wrong?
I have looked on other articles, but they didn't seem to help.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist. Then [edit] your question to give us more details, including a proper [mre].

Is there a space after the %d in the format string?  Your code doesn't show one, but were you completely careful when transcribing (pasting) your code into the question?  That could cause the problem.  Enter a letter or digit after the number and see what happens.

Your environment does not flush stdout upon reading from stdin tied to the terminal.  You should flush the output manually:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    for (;;) {
        printf("What is your guess?\n--> ");
        fflush(stdout);
        int guess;
        if (scanf("%d", &guess) != 1) {
            printf("missing or invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (guess == 42) {
            printf("you win!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        if (guess < 42) {
            printf("too small! try again\n");
        } else {
            printf("too large! try again\n");
        }
    }
}

